# How to change a timestamp from character to datetime in R and add missing timestamps

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp, format

I have got a data frame with different columns.
One column is called "TIMESTAMP". Click on the column, I see it is a character, down below you see the content:

```
TIMESTAMP             Price
2003-06-20 09:19:00   5.25
2003-06-20 09:21:00   5.34
2003-06-20 09:22:00   5.43
2003-06-20 09:23:00   5.32
```

I'd like to convert the complete "TIMESTAMP"-column into `as.POSIXct`
The reason for this is, that I want to afterwards add the missing minutes in the column as you see from row 1 to 2 there is the timestamp missing with `09:20:00`. I want to add the missing minutes for `09:00:00` to `17:30:00`, of course with the correct date too.

Let's call the dataframe `data`.
I tried `as.POSIXct(data$TIMESTAMP, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`, but I m unsure if it was succesfull, because the data in the dataframe didn't change.

Is there also a hint how to add the missing timestamps after getting the correct format?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tried is correct as long as you assign the result back to the column of your data frame. This is what you should do:

```
> data$TIMESTAMP <- as.POSIXct(data$TIMESTAMP, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

After that, the `TIMESTAMP` column will have the desired class:

```
> class(data$TIMESTAMP)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

For completing your data frame with missing lines, you can first build a new `data.frame` with all the expected times and then merge it to your initial data. Bellow I'm using `min` and `max` to find the range of date-time, then I'm using `seq.POSIXt` by minute to generate the full set of date-time. The merge will then use the already existing price values from your initial data frame:

```
> data_full <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP = seq.POSIXt(from=min(data$TIMESTAMP), to=max(data$TIMESTAMP), by='min'))
> data_complete <- merge(data_full, data, all.x = T)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Another short question... if I have a time like `14:10:30.54`, so with milliseconds in the end, how do I get a result without the milliseconds, e.g. `14:10:30`?

Comment: The `as.POSIXct` function used in the above answer will discard the milliseconds as shown in this example:

`> as.POSIXct('2003-06-20 09:19:00.435', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

ẁhich leads

`[1] "2003-06-20 09:19:00 CEST"`